# Unity SQLite Database autoincrement not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

This is the asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/sqlite-database-40375#description
It has a documentation, but it's quite poor and not really helpful.

```
private void CreateUserTable(){
        DBSchema schema = new DBSchema("Users");
        schema.AddField("ID", SQLiteDB.DB_DataType.DB_INT, 0, false, true, true);
        schema.AddField("Email", SQLiteDB.DB_DataType.DB_VARCHAR, 100, false, false, false);
        schema.AddField("Password", SQLiteDB.DB_DataType.DB_VARCHAR, 255, false, false, false);
        schema.AddField("RegistrationDate", SQLiteDB.DB_DataType.DB_VARCHAR, 0, false, false, false);
        schema.AddField("isVerified", SQLiteDB.DB_DataType.DB_INT, 0, false, false, false);

        bool created = db.CreateTable(schema);
        Debug.Log("Users Table Created: " + created);
    }
```

this is the table.
while this is the function I call to add a new "user":

```
public void AddUser(string email, string password){
        List<SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair> dataPairList = new List<SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair>();

        // Email
        SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair emailData = new SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair();
        emailData.fieldName = "Email";
        emailData.value = email;
        dataPairList.Add(emailData);

        // Password
        SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair passwordData = new SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair();
        passwordData.fieldName = "Password";
        passwordData.value = password;
        dataPairList.Add(passwordData);

        // RegistrationDate
        SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair regdateData = new SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair();
        regdateData.fieldName = "RegistrationDate";
        regdateData.value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dataPairList.Add(regdateData);

        // IsVerified
        SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair verifiedData = new SQLiteDB.DB_DataPair();
        verifiedData.fieldName = "IsVerified";
        verifiedData.value = "0";
        dataPairList.Add(verifiedData);

        // Insert the data into the "Users" table
        int added = db.Insert("Users", dataPairList);
        Debug.Log("Users added: " + added);
    }
```

It doesn't give any error and actually adds the user into the db. It seems to work really fine.
But when I try to get the IDs of users registered with this function:

```
public long GetID(string email){
        string query = $"SELECT ID FROM Users WHERE Email = '{email}'";
        DBReader reader = db.Select(query);

        if (reader != null && reader.Read()){
            long id = reader.GetIntValue("ID");
            return id;
        }
        
        return -1;
    }
```

Doesn't matter what email I enter (I'm talking about correct emails, wrong emails don't return anything), the ID returned is always 0.

I would really love to find a solution without using another asset (mostly because I like this one - I handle everything with C# scripts, so I have full control). But of course if you know another good (and maybe not too expensive) asset I could use it would be ok too.

I tried registering some users.
I put emails and passwords and they got registered.

If I try to login as a user that doesn't exist (no corresponding email) it fails (as expected).
If I try to login as a user that exists, it should return the ID number (and it does), but it always returns 0.

I expect first user registered to have ID=0 (and it does).
Then I expect the second user registered to have ID=1 (but it has 0).
And so on ...

Comment: Ive no idea what the fields of the addfield are but i dont see you setting up a primary key

Comment: As for what I understood, the second bool argument of AddField determine if the Field is a Primary Key.

What I understood, those 3 bool arguments are:
1) Nullable.
2) Primary Key
3) Auto-Increment